# Problems once migrate jsf 1.2 to jsf 2.2.12

Tags: maven, jsf, jboss, linkageerror

I am migrating project from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2.2.12. After built successful, I deployed to the jboss 7 server and got error message like that:

```
14:14:10,255 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject-war.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject-war.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myproject-war.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.richfaces.taglib.ColumnsTag with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myproject-war.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getParent()Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/richfaces/taglib/ColumnsTag, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag have different Class objects for the type ervlet/jsp/tagext/Tag; used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2509) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1819) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more

14:14:10,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "myproject-war.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject-war.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject-war.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myproject-war.war\""}}
14:14:10,484 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myproject-war.war in 198ms
14:14:10,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject-war.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myproject-war.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myproject-war.war"

[2015-09-30 02:14:10,579] Artifact myproject-war:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2015-09-30 02:14:10,579] Artifact myproject-war:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject-war.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"myproject-war.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myproject-war.war\""}}
```

Could you have any idea for this one?

Here are my system detail:
Server: jboss7
Current libs: jsf 1.2, richfaces 3.3.3
Migration libs: jsf 2.2.17
Build: maven

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getParent()Ljavax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/richfaces/taglib/ColumnsTag, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for interface javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/Tag have different Class objects for the type ervlet/jsp/tagext/Tag; used in the signature

`java.lang.LinkageError` is sign of classpath pollution with multiple different versioned libraries. You'd best let Maven produce a WAR file and then inspect its `/WEB-INF/lib` for any libraries which doesn't belong there (i.e. libraries which are supposed to be already provided by the target server, such as Java EE, JSP, Servlet, JSF, etc.. in your case with JBoss AS). Then fix the Maven `pom.xml` accordingly to mark exactly those as `provided`.

The particular one you got suggests a duplicated `javax.servlet.jsp.*` API. You'll in `/WEB-INF/lib` most likely have a `jsp-api.jar` or another JAR which covers this (e.g. `javaee.jar`). In that case, you need to mark exactly that dependency in `pom.xml` as `provided`. Or, if it's actually `jsp-api`, then just remove it altogether and use a single `javaee-api` or `javaee-web-api` dependency with version `6.0` and scope `provided` which covers the entire Java EE 6 (Web profile) already, exactly as done by JBoss AS 7.